# Buying new pc but don't want to reinstall everything

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have dual boot Ubuntu and Windows 10, and installed a lot of software in both OS. Recently there seems to be some hardware problem with my pc and I am planning to buy a new one, probably Lenovo. That means I will have to reinstall Ubuntu, as well as all programs in both OS, which will take weeks. Is there some way to avoid this? I am thinking about making an image of my whole hard disk and then format the new one and copy the image to the new hard disk. Is that a stupid method? And how to do it? Or are there cleverer ways? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Reinstalling the system + all the software takes **at most** 2 hours on ubuntu, even less depending on your hardware and connection, but you have to do it cleverly. From Synaptic go to File>Save Selections and then on the new system go to File>Read Selections, then apply the modifications.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu: not a problem. If you remove the proprietary drivers (and even that is not always needed) from Ubuntu you can take out the hard disk and put it into the other system. Or create a dump from the whole disk (with `dd`) and copy it over to the other system. Not saying it will be quick or that this method is user-friendly but it is possible.

And as in comments: 2 hours tops for installing Ubuntu. Maybe an extra hour for all the extras you need. With 1 comment: during the install you can still use your machine and use the internet. All you need to do is set up your internet before the install. Oh and a 15, 20 minutes install time if you start using SDDs.

Windows ... off topic  ... but no such luck. You even need to buy a new license (it will come with the new system) and will need to re-install everything.

Answer (score 1):

On the Ubuntu side you can backup all apps and configurations in [Aptik](http://www.tecmint.com/aptik-a-tool-to-backuprestore-your-favourite-ppas-and-apps-in-ubuntu/) and then restoring it in the new PC.

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install aptik
```

Windows 10 is off-topic.